# What is trailing closure syntax in Swift?

Tags: swift

Swift's [documentation on closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) states:

> Swift’s closure expressions have a clean, clear style, with optimizations that encourage brief, clutter-free syntax in common scenarios. These optimizations include:
>
> - Inferring parameter and return value types from context
> - Implicit returns from single-expression closures
> - Shorthand argument names
> - **Trailing closure syntax**

What exactly is "trailing closure syntax" for Swift closures?

Comment: First result on Google by typing `swift trailing closure`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-trailing-closure-syntax

Answer (score 9):

A trailing closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as part of the function call.

```
func doSomething(number:Int, onSuccess closure:(Int)->Void) {

    closure(number * number * number)

}

doSomething(number: 100) { (numberCube) in

    print(numberCube) // prints  1000000

}
```

The argument label onSuccess is not there in the function call. Even though the closure is included in the function parameters list, swift will take it out of the parameter block to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 3):

> 2. A closure expression that is written outside of (and after) the
>      parentheses of the function call it supports

It is just syntactic sugar to write less and is easier to read.

Giving you a use case:

You have a function that needs a another function (or closure) as a parameter like that:

```
func fooFunc(paramfunc: () -> Void) {
    paramfunc();
}
```

Calling the function and giving a function as an argument is normal. Giving it a closure means the argument you give is a nameless function written between `{}` and with the type signature in the beginning (it is an anonymous function).

While calling a function which needs a function as argument and writing the closure after the parenthesis or omitting the parenthesis if it is the only argument (multiple trailing closures coming in Swift 5.3) makes it trailing closure syntax.

```
fooFunc { () -> Void in
    print("Bar");
}

fooFunc() { () -> Void in
    print("Bar");
}
```

*The parenthesis after the function name can even be omitted.*

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as part of the function call.

```
 func funcWithATrailingClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
// function body goes here
 }

// Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:
funcWithATrailingClosure(closure: {
// closure's body goes here
})

// Here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:
funcWithATrailingClosure() {
// trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

Comment: `()` can also be omitted. `someFunctionThatTakesAClosure { }`

Answer (score 1):

When the last parameter of a function is a closure like this:

```
class Object {
  func foo(bar: String, baz: (() -> Void)) { }
}
```

You can call it normally like:

```
let obj = Object()
obj.foo(bar: "", baz: { foo() })
```

or trailing like this

```
obj.foo(bar: "") { foo() }
```

Also, in case of having multiple trailing closure like this:

```
func foo(bar: String, baz: (() -> Void), pippo: ((IndexPath) -> Void)) { }
```

then if you try to call it like:

```
obj.foo(bar: "") { _ in

} pippo: { _ in

}
```

following error occurs:

**Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored**

So prevent that error you need to call like:

```
obj.foo(bar: "") {

} pippo: { _ in
    
}
```

Finally, if you want to use one more closure type like Int

```
func foo(bar: String, baz: ((Int) -> Void), pippo: ((IndexPath) -> Void)) { }
```

then call like:

```
obj.foo(bar: "") { _ in //baz

} pippo: { _ in
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> #### Trailing Closures
>
> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as part of the function call.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
}

// Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
    // closure's body goes here
})

// Here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

> If a closure expression is provided as the function or method’s only argument and you provide that expression as a trailing closure, you do not need to write a pair of parentheses () after the function or method’s name when you call the function:

```
reversedNames = names.sorted { $0 > $1 }
```

Comment: `()` can also be omitted. `someFunctionThatTakesAClosure { }`