# swift - Initializing the UIContextualAction class

Tags: swift, initializer

***UIContextualAction*** class has an initializer with the following signature.

```
public convenience init(style: UIContextualAction.Style, title: String?, handler: @escaping UIContextualAction.Handler)
```

An instance of the ***UIContextualAction*** class can be created using the following code snippet.

```
let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
     completion(true)
}
```

What I don't understand is the way that the 3rd parameter (i.e. ***handler***) is passed to the class initializer.

Why is the handler function is passed inside separate curly braces without passing it after passing the value for the ***delete*** parameter?

Are there any other ways which we can get the same output?

Comment: That's a closure, and a way of writing them and it's explained there: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These both way of writing are the same:

```
let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
    completion(true)
}

let action2 = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
    completion(true)
})
```

You can have a look at the documentation of [Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102):

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though
>   it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing
>   closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as
>   part of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Because the 3rd parameter

```
let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
 completion(true)
}
```

is a trailing closure that you expect it to be triggered to run some related code when the user hits the delete action and it's not a parameter to init the alert action

you can also path nil if you don't need to do anything

```
let action2 = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete", handler:nil)
```

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-trailing-closure-syntax

[What is trailing closure syntax in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762145/what-is-trailing-closure-syntax-in-swift)