# Swift 5 Closures explained

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have this code which queries a Firebase Realtime Db.

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    ref.observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
        // more code
    }
})
```

Here we can see two examples of closure. On the first one everything is inside `observe()` and on the second one we call `observe()` and then we use the closure as a callback function.

My question is:

In the first line: Are we using the closure as a parameter?
On the second one: Are we using it as a callback function?

If this is the case a totally understand the second approach but i don't understand the first line and why we write a closure like that.

Comment: Both are calling the same `observe` method.  Swift has a feature called *trailing closure syntax* which allows you to leave off the last parameter if it is a closure and have it follow the call.  So both calls pass the closure as `"with"`, and the `observe` method will call it something like `with(snapshotValue)`.

Comment: @vacawama you should post your comment as an answer. You might want to add a link to Apple's, or somebody else's docs on trailing closure syntax as well. It's pretty confusing when you're first learning Swift, and a very convenient shorthand once you get used to it.

Comment: You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36762145/2395636).

Comment: 2 variations of the syntax are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628125/5820010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are calling the same `observe` method. Swift has a feature called **trailing closure syntax** which allows you to leave off the last argument if it is a closure and have it follow the call.

So both calls to `observe` pass the closure as `"with"`, and the `observe` method will call that closure using a call like `with(snapshotValue)`.

See the *Trailing Closures* section of the [Swift Documentation on Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Quoting from the start of that documentation:

> **Trailing Closures**
>
> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though
>   it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing
>   closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as
>   part of the function call.

Comment: you are talking about the  inner call right? `ref.observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
        // more code
    }` here we are leaving off the last argument ?

Comment: @RexhinHoxha, yes.  The inner call that leaves off the last argument and the outer call which includes it are the same.  If you wanted, you could write the inner call like the outer one, or you could write the outer one like the inner one.  They are just two ways of expressing the same thing.